# Manipulate History Back with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently working on a PHP 5.3 based CMS. A lot of actions are called using GET Parameters.

Example:

```
index.php?action=create_module
```

adds a certain module to the database and displays the module structure again. There are also functions (triggered by simple links, no POST request) for removing and ordering modules, working the same way with GET parameters.

Problem with this: If the users clicks on **History Back** after two actions on that page, the whole action is triggered *again*, which I would like to avoid.

How can I solve this issue? Searched the internet already, but with no satisfying results.

- Is there a jQuery function which can remove this ?action parameter when using the browser Back button?
- If not, can I prevent the browser from going back?
- Is there a way to trigger this "Page has expired" notice?
- Different approach on the PHP side?

Note: Header("Location:..") is no option, and I would like to avoid AJAX here.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are they filling out forums or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener on 'onpopstate' to clean window.location.search which holds the parameters, see http://html5doctor.com/history-api/ to get more info about HistoryAPI.